# Images to HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: python, google-glass, http-live-streaming, google-mirror-api

I have a series of video frames as images that have been processed using some algorithm. I now want to stream these in a format that Google Glass can read ([instructions](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/static-cards?hl=en#attaching_video) and [formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)).

How would I go about encoding these images into a video and serving them as an HTTP Live Streaming video URL in Python?

Comment: With [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-1) . [Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images)

Comment: I know how to create a video from images, but I don't know how to make a streaming video server from a series of images.

Comment: Since it's **HTTP** Live Streaming you don't need a video server, just a regular HTTP server. You output the playlists/segments to a web-accessible directory and serve them with the right MIME types. `ffmpeg` can do both VOD/Live and there's also a `ffserver` in the same project.